# Knit to pdf error in R - Error: Failed to compile

Tags: r, pdf

Need help. I have installed `tinytex`, `miktex`

I get this error when I knit to pdf

`output file: test_knit.knit.md`

> Error:   Failed to compile test_knit.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
>     '"pdflatex"' not found
>   Execution halted
>
> No LaTeX installation detected (LaTeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a LaTeX distribution for your platform: https://www.latex-project.org/get/
>
> If you are not sure, you may install TinyTeX in R: tinytex::install_tinytex()
>
> Otherwise consider MiKTeX on Windows - http://miktex.org
>
> MacTeX on macOS - https://tug.org/mactex/
>     (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome *strongly* recommended)
>
> Linux: Use system package manager

Comment: You read through that tinytex debugging link and it didn't help?

Comment: tried to add  ```{r optionset}
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)

Comment: processing file: test_knit.rmd.....stuck here for 15mins...?